# RocketMq:how can get RocketMQ topic and tags using Api

Tags: rocketmq

How can I get all the tags in the topic of RocketMQ

Answer (score 0):

it seems cannot be done for now.
when consumeing the topic, consumers would get all tags

Comment: thank you for your reply. So only consumers who consume this topic can get the tags, right?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Tags are only stored in messages, there is no global place to store all tags of a topic, so only consumers can specify tags for filtering and consumption

Answer (score 0):

You can't! Since there are no ways to save all tags in the broker.

Actually, you need not know all the tags when you consume. You should only care about the tag you know. If there are some tags that a consumer does not know, which means the messages with that tag should not be consumed by it.